# Choosing inductor for LM2596-ADJ regulator

Tags: voltage-regulator

I want to use LM2596-ADJ as regulator for SIM800C to convert my 5V input voltage to 4V with 3A current. I obtained the capacity of output inductor equal to 15uH based on datasheet instructions but i couldn't find an inductor with this capacity in the local stores. so can i use an inductor with a higher value instead?

Comment: Show your circuit and provide a link to the LM data sheet please. Put these into your question and not in comments.

Comment: You usually won't find specialised inductors in your local hobby store. Buy them online from distributors like element14, mouser or digikey. Also, make sure your inductor can handle at least 3 amps(unless you want the magic smoke to come out).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inductor should be a [shielded](https://www.tme.eu/cz/details/de1207-33/vykonne-tlumivky-smd/ferrocore/) one, I use [murata](https://www.murata.com/~/media/webrenewal/support/library/catalog/products/inductor/chip/o05e.ashx). if the environment does not require shielding, you can use a different one. The minimum current should be 3.5A, because the regulator LM2596 uses 3A max.

According to the datasheet the inductor is 68 μH. You can not convert 5V to 4V, because the voltage drop is 1.23V. 3.8V will work with your module.

Comment: can i use an inductor with higher value than 68 μH if i couldn't find it in stores?

Comment: Normally +-20% do not matter. You have to test it out for your application, or better yet with an osciloscope to see the ripple and how your device will take it.  68uH is a common inductor, it should be present in all stores, including AliExpress. You can try with 47uH or 100uH maximum. [Link] https://s.click.aliexpress.com/e/_dZ9hjk8 [Link] https://www.tme.eu/cz/katalog/vykonne-tlumivky-smd_112360/?s_order=desc&search=68uH&s_field=1000011

Comment: i checked the datasheet and i think the 68 μH inductor is only used for the test circuit and for other situations i should calculate the inductor capacity using the procedure that is exists in datasheet for adjustable version.

Comment: You have Test Circuit and Layout Guidelines, it says L1 = 68uH. You will have no problem with this value.